# How can i change apex:sectionHeader text color?

Tags: visualforce

I need to change apex:sectionHeader text colour to green but i didn't find and style attribute there to change that.. So can anyone explain how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this CSS style:

```
.pageDescription, .pageType {
    color: green !important;
}
```